# Vertical alignment of one div within another not working

Tags: html, css

This is a cut down version of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/f6GCz/

I'm trying to vertically center the "learn more" box using this code:

```
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
```

What would cause this box not to be centered vertically? Even when I apply a width to it it doesnt work. Cross browser solutions (IE8+) preferred!

Comment: in `position:absolute;` no work `margin:auto;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use absolute positioning, add this to your "learn more" box css:

```
left:50%;
width:90px;
margin-left:-45px;
```

Where the margin-left is always 1/2 of the container width.

**Update**

If you don't have to use absolute, then give the div a width and set the margin to:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

If desired, the width can be a percentage instead of a `px` value.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32PwC/2/) with both results.

**Update Two**

If you want to align your learn more box without specifying it as absolute, put it inside a footer container that is positioned at the bottom, then use `margin:0 auto` on it. Something like this: [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/8S5Ys/)

Comment: What about if i dont have to use absolute?

Comment: Really sorry to be a pain, but just for clarity. With the new approach the learn more box doesnt sit on the bottom and ```vertical-align: bottom``` doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/32PwC/3/

Comment: That's correct, `margin:auto` will not work with an absolutely positioned div, and you can't position the div with `bottom:0` unless you have an absolute positioned div. A compromise could be to have a footer container and then your learn more box in it. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8S5Ys/